# Strange Iterator behavior

Tags: c++

I have encountered strange behavior of iterators on empty `<vector>`. In my code, even though `std::cend(children) - 1 - std::cbegin(children)` is clearly negative (`0 -1 -0`), their comparison `std::cbegin(children) < (std::cend(children) - 1)` result is `true` ( `0 < (0-1)`). Is this compiler bug or language specification or undefined behavior ?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    std::vector<int> children{};

    auto pointer_to_child_first = std::cbegin(children);
    auto pointer_to_child_last = std::cend(children) - 1;
    auto pointer_to_child_current = pointer_to_child_first;

    for (; pointer_to_child_current < pointer_to_child_last; pointer_to_child_current += 1) {
        std::cout << ">if less code\n";
    }

    if (pointer_to_child_current == pointer_to_child_last) {
        std::cout << ">if equals code\n";
    }
}
```

Output:

```
>if less code
>if less code
>if less code
>if less code
>if less code
^C
```

If I change `std::cbegin`and `std::cend` to `std::crbegin` and `std::crend` or to `std::crend` and `std::crbegin`, than I got all as intended.

Compiler version:

```
>clang-cl.exe -v
clang version 8.0.0 (tags/RELEASE_800/final)
Target: x86_64-pc-windows-msvc
```

Comment: Note that there is pretty much no benefit from having `const` on a non-reference non-pointer return type. It will impeded move semantics and some optimizations.

Comment: can you reduce your code to a [mcve]? I have difficulties to understand all the code and I believe most of it is not related to the question. On the other hand what you see could be caused by undefined behvior somewhere else in your code. In that case you cannot reproduce the same with only a vector and iterators, but even that would be valuable information

Comment: Your code [has undefined behavior](https://wandbox.org/permlink/y3zIDxxK5r9mzq3Z).

Comment: `std::cend(children) - 1` is illegal when `children.size() == 0`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What happens when you're looking at a leaf node (a node with no children)? Specifically, what will this line do:

```
auto&& pointer_to_child_last = std::cend(children) - 1;
```

Since `std::cbegin(children) == std::cend(children)`, this is illegal!

To remedy this, if the node is a leaf, just return your accumulator string after you've added the node number:

```
if(children.size() == 0) { return accumulator.str(); }
```

See it in action: http://ideone.com/1oh9yr

Comment: So is this an undefined behavior ? And why there is no problems with `std::crbegin` and `std::crend` ?

Comment: @darkside take a look at [this info-graphic](http://upload.cppreference.com/mwiki/images/3/39/range-rbegin-rend.svg). Both are undefined behavior, but if you use the reverse iterators, everything is backwards, so it's just different undefined behavior. Both are illegal.

Comment: Thanks for answer, I was curios why, so i found out in standart that for <vector> `::iterator` is any "that meets the forward iterator requirements" and `::reverse_iterator` is `reverse_iterator<iterator>`.  Also "Just as a regular pointer to an array guarantees ... value pointing past the last element of the array, so for any iterator type there is an iterator value that points past the last element of a corresponding sequence. These values are called _past-the-end_ values_" To sum up, there is no guarantee for forward iterators of having before-the-end values, but maybe is for bidirectional.

Comment: and in `reverse_iterator<Iterator>`,  "The template parameter `Iterator` shall meet all the requirements of a Bidirectional Iterator"